# How to use tf.data.Dataset and tf.keras do multi-inputs and multi-outpus?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I meet one question about multi-output using tf.keras to build model and also using tf.data.Dataset as the input pipeline. Here is my code below:

```
  a = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(368, 368, 3))
  conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, 1)(a)
  conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, 1)(conv1)
  maxpool = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=8, strides=8, 
   padding='same')(conv2)
  conv3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(5, 1, 1)(maxpool)
  conv4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(6, 1, 1)(maxpool)

  inputs = a
  outputs = [conv3, conv4]

  model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)


  model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(),
          loss=tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error)


  import numpy as np
  data = np.random.rand(10, 368, 368, 3)
  cpm  = np.random.rand(10, 46, 46, 5)
  paf  = np.random.rand(10, 46, 46, 6)

  dataset1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data))
  dataset2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((cpm, paf))
  dataset1 = dataset1.batch(10).repeat()
  dataset2 = dataset2.batch(10).repeat()

  dataset  = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset1, dataset2))

  model.fit(dataset, epochs=200, steps_per_epoch=30)
```

I'm using tensorflow==1.10.1 and I got error like this:

```
 File "/home/ulsee/work/tensorflow-HalfBodyPose/learnkeras.py", line 123, in <module>
model.fit(dataset, epochs=200, steps_per_epoch=30)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1278, in fit
validation_split=validation_split)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 917, in _standardize_user_data
exception_prefix='target')
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 143, in standardize_input_data
data = [standardize_single_array(x) for x in data]
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 143, in <listcomp>
data = [standardize_single_array(x) for x in data]
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 81, in standardize_single_array
elif x.ndim == 1:
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

**Update** :
I have made this code work after i upgrading tf==1.11.0. So maybe i think it's a version bug.

Comment: I'm no Tensorflow expert, but it looks like you're giving it a tuple where it expects a tensor. Best guess that's your `outputs`.

Comment: dataset1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data))
  dataset2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((cpm, paf))
Looking at your network, your input to the network should be (batch_size, 368, 368, 3). Is there a reason why you are doing the above 2 steps and then building a complex dataset?

Comment: @kvish, because i have two outputs for this model, so i want to pass two labels in dataset, that's why i doing the 2 steps for building a complex dataset. I'm not sure this way is right or not, could you give me some advice for that? Thanks.

Comment: @Matthew Hou I have written a suggestion in the answer. Feel free to check if that is something that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to concatenate your outputs and then do the same for your target numpy arrays. Whether it makes sense for your application logic wise is something I am not sure.

```
def conc_op(tensors):
    return K.concatenate(tensors) # K refers to Keras backend

def conc_op_shape(input_shapes):
    shape1 = list(input_shapes[0])
    shape2 = list(input_shapes[1])
    return tuple(shape1[:-1], shape1[-1]+shape2[-1])

a = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(368, 368, 3))
conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, 1)(a)
conv2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, 1)(conv1)
maxpool = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=8, strides=8, padding='same')(conv2)
conv3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(5, 1, 1)(maxpool)
conv4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(6, 1, 1)(maxpool)

inputs = a
outputs = [conv3, conv4]
conc_outputs = Lambda(conc_op, output_shape=conc_op_shape)(outputs) # This is a keras layer
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=conc_outputs)

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(), loss=keras.losses.mean_squared_error)
model.summary()
data = np.random.rand(10, 368, 368, 3)
cpm  = np.random.rand(10, 46, 46, 5)
paf  = np.random.rand(10, 46, 46, 6)
label = np.concatenate((cpm, paf), axis=-1)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data, label))
dataset = dataset.batch(2).repeat()
model.fit(dataset.make_one_shot_iterator(), epochs=2, steps_per_epoch=5) # Just to check if it runs
```

Returns the Result:

```
Epoch 1/2
5/5 [==============================] - 15s 3s/step - loss: 0.4057
Epoch 2/2
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 32ms/step - loss: 0.2282
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. Actually i make mine code work after i upgrading tf==1.11.0. So maybe i think it is a version bug. But also thanks for your kind.

Comment: @Matthew Hou thats great! Interesting that it got fixed with an upgrade